# make a list of dictionaries where key-value pairs are web elements' inner text, scraped using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, nested-lists

I do web scraping using *Selenium* library in **Python**. "Links" is a list of links for apartments(for rent). I need to iterate through and scrape key info about each apartment, so in the end, I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
key_data = [{'Property type': 'Wohnung', 'room': '3', 'Floor': '1. Stock', 'Living space': '57 m²', 'Year of construction': 'not available'}].
```

Cannot come up with a pythonic, short way to do it. My code:

```
key_data = []
for link in links:
    url = link
    driver.get(url)
    hdrs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("css-cyiock.excbu0j2")#list of web elements
    undrhdrs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("css-1ush3w6.excbu0j2")#list of emelements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, posting here for anyone who has the same issue. Please feel free to suggest a better solution.

```
key_data = []
for link in links:
    url = link
    driver.get(url)
    hdrs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("css-cyiock.excbu0j2")
    undrhdrs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("css-1ush3w6.excbu0j2")
    keyd_dict = {k.get_attribute("innerText"): v.get_attribute("innerText") for k, v in zip(hdrs, undrhdrs)}
    key_data.append(keyd_dict)
```